# Mvc переменные

Tags: mvc, php

```
<?php
class Model {
    public $db;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = 'test';
    }
}

class Model_index extends Model {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }   
}

class users extends Model {
    public function __construct() { }
    function test()
    {
        var_dump($this->db); // Как сделать без new model, чтобы переменная была доступна в данном классе
    }
}

new Model_index;
$users = new users;
$users->test();
```

Comment: Если задаешь public static $db; то появляется ошибка Notice: Undefined property: users::$db

Answer (score 1):

Вот так должно быть:

```
class users extends Model {
    public function __construct() { 
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function test()
    {
        var_dump($this->db); // Как сделать без new model, чтобы переменная была доступна в данном классе
    }
}
```

Comment: 502 ошибка появляется

Comment: 502? Настраивайте сервер. Все работает ТОЧНО! Инфа 100%

Answer (score 0):

Объявите её как static, пишу с телефона,не могу привести пример кода...

Comment: Если переменная объявлена, как static, то обращаться к ней надо через self::$db